# Запятая в сочетании "все что могли"

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в таком варианте: "все(,) что могли сотрудники обсуждали..."

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая в сочетании: все что могли сотрудники обсудили на конферении

Answer (score 1):

"Все, что могли, сотрудники обсудили на конференции".
Хотя есть хитрость - область уточнения. Например "Все, что могли сотрудники, обсудили их начальники на совещании по премированию за квартал" :) По аналогии с "казнить нельзя помиловать"...

Answer (score 0):

Да, это сложное предложение, запятыми выделяется внутренняя конструкция.